# How can I see my DirectoryIndex order on a shared web server?

Tags: apache-2.2, shared-hosting, directoryindex

How can I view the default DirectoryIndex order? Is there a command I can run?

I'm on a shared web server so I can't view the configuration file. Is the default documented anywhere? My Google-fu is failing today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value is documented here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

But, distributions may also provide their own defaults.  For instance, Ubuntu 10.04 LTS has the following default:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
```

(specified in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf)

If you don't have access to the configuration tree, there is no command you can run either.  In that case, the best solution would be to just ask the administrator(s) of the server.

Comment: I completely missed that the default was listed there. I expected there to be more then just index.html.